# Why java doesn't support local objects?

Tags: java

Why java doesn't allow stack allocated or say local objects? Stack allocated objects are good for runtime efficiency.

Comment: This design decision is already explained, JIT must handle that, and not the programmer. For more words, try searching the web.

Answer (score 3):

Java does support it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis

But I don't know how good the analysis is.

Comment: +1 The analysis isn't very effective AFAIK.